# Setting a Kaggle environment with GPU

Tags: gpu, kaggle

I'm new to Kaggle Notebooks I've been working with Google colab when I want access to cloud `GPU`/`TPU` I've been trying to set a notebook with `GPU` In Kaggle but I don't see any settings for GPU environment.

This is my new notebook.

[image]

Can someone show me how I can set a notebook with GPU on Kaggle kennels.

Comment: There should be an accelerator option right side. Also, can you check that three vertical dot and search accelerator options?

Comment: The three dots are showing me these 3 options  `Restart and clear all outputs`, `view session metrics` and `upgrade to google AI notebooks`.

Comment: Try some public notebooks, fork them and see if it's the same. Or, create a notebook from a competition page (later you can remove the complete data set and insert your own). If either case, you face the same issue, post your problem in the kaggle forum (product) - they're active.

Comment: Okay thank you for your comment i really appreciate them

Comment: For those who have the same problem: make sure your account is verified.

Answer (score 1):

As [@kodkod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/536650/kodkod) said in the coments, verifying my telephone number worked for me. I follwed those steps.

> Simple pathway to verification for the current version of Kaggle:
>
> Click profile icon on top right corner of your page > Click Account,
> or From left panel of your page: click Your Work > click Account tab >
> scroll down to Phone Verification > click Not verified link > enter
> your mobile phone number > enter the verification code sent to your
> mobile phone and you're done!

I hope this works for you.